# SQLite leaked data errors, and other random errors

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

When starting my application, it should only create an SQLite database. However, according to the logcat, a database is created, one row is inserted, then the database is created again. 
It then says that;

```
A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.example.wolfe_000.final_final_zeno/databases/User_Info' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

I have previously attempted closing the database after interacting with it, it did not seem to work for me. I would really appreciate some advice, I'm new to SQLite and I'm completely lost. Here is the code;

```
package com.example.wolfe_000.final_final_zeno;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by wolfe_000 on 19/04/2015.
 */
public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static int database_version = 1;
public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME + "(" + TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME +" TEXT," + TableData.TableInfo.USER_WEIGHT +" TEXT," + TableData.TableInfo.USER_GOAL +" TEXT," + TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS +" TEXT," + TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL +" TEXT);";


public DatabaseOperations(Context context) {
    super(context, TableData.TableInfo.DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
    Log.d("Database Operations", "Database Created");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb) {
    sdb.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
    Log.d("Database Operations", "Database Created");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {

}

public void putInformation(DatabaseOperations dop, String name, String pass, String email, String weight, String goal) {
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME, name);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS, pass);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL, email);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_WEIGHT, weight);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_GOAL, goal);
    long k = SQ.insert(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    Log.d("Database Operations", "One Raw Inserted");
}

public Cursor getInformation(DatabaseOperations dop){
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME, TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS, TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL, TableData.TableInfo.USER_WEIGHT, TableData.TableInfo.USER_GOAL};
    Cursor CR = SQ.query(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    return CR;
}
```

}

Comment: You need to call `SQ.close()` method for close your database in your both methods. While you'r performing your both operations you haven't closed your database.

Answer (score 0):

you need just close Your database which you open...

```
DatabaseOperations mHelper = new DatabaseOperations(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
//your other operation like cursor and adapter...

db.close();
```

Comment: Like this for example just on this function?
                                              
`public void putInformation(DatabaseOperations dop, String name,String pass, String email, String weight, String goal) {
        SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME, name);
        long k = SQ.insert(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        Log.d("Database Operations", "One Raw Inserted");
        SQ.close();
    }`

Comment: Yes exertly sq.close() after your all work completed of database as like insert,delet etc